# resize title in uitableviewcellstyledefault

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

i've been trying around for a while now and cant seem to find a solution. i am using a `UITableViewCellStyleDefault` cellstyle in my tableview, and am trying to get the font to resize when the text gets too long.

**cell creation**

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"thisMonthCell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;

    [cell.textLabel setTextColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
    [cell.textLabel setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth:YES];
    [cell.textLabel setMinimumFontSize:14];

    UILabel *valueLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(190, 10, 100, 20)];
    [valueLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    valueLabel.tag = 1001;
    [valueLabel setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentRight];
    [cell addSubview:valueLabel];

}

Expense *expense = [[self.dataHandler monthExpenses]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

UILabel *value = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:1001];
[cell.textLabel setText:[expense name]];

if ([[expense value]doubleValue] > 0) {
    [value setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"+%.2f",[[expense value]doubleValue]]];
    [value setTextColor:[self greenColor]];    

}
else{
    [value setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",[[expense value]doubleValue]]];
    [value setTextColor:[self redColor]];    
}
return cell;
```

but somehow the `textLabel` wont resize if the text is too long.

here is a screenshot demonstrating the problem:

[image: autosize fail]

any ideas?

**UPDATE** i managed to achieve my goal by removing the standardLabel and adding a custom one,.. weird that it would not work with the standard one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this `cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;` `cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap`

Answer (score 0):

Use following two line of code also when you are creating value label.

```
valueLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
valueLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
```

EDITED-
To change the height of cell -

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *cellText = @"oooooooooooooooooooo"; //Text that you are using
    UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:16.0]; //Whatever font you are using.
    CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(280.0f, MAXFLOAT);
    CGSize labelSize = [cellText sizeWithFont:cellFont constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    return labelSize.height + 25.0; //25.0 is offset, you can change as per need
```

}

Comment: i added them - but it doesnt change anything (its `textLabel` that gets too long not valuelable)

Comment: valueLabel.numberOfLines = INT_MAX ..can you check with this statement once.

Comment: is there any specific reason for using two labels, one is cells's text label and another value label?

Comment: Also one thing is missed that is changing the height of table view cell dynamically, we need to change that also.

Comment: yes there is :) the height of the tableviewcell is right :)
i added a screenshot to make clear what is the problem.

Comment: i dont think we are on the same page altought i really appreciate your help. i will not change the heigt of the row (thats what height for row) is for - not for the cells content). i need to change the fontsize of textlabel automatically as 'resizetofit' normally would do..

Comment: Might be you can try following method - setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth, to adjust the font size.

Comment: see my code thats what i had the whole time and it doesnt work ;-) this is why i posted the question, i actually do know how to work with tableviews :P

Comment: @SebastianFlückiger - issue is fixed, we just got into a wrong track. good learning :)